# Запрет двойной авторизации через session php одного и того же акаунтаL

Tags: php, сессия

Доброго времени! Реализовал на сайте авторизацию пользователей через сессии php
точнее к примеру есть переменные в сеесиях $_SESSION['ulogin'] и $_SESSION['upassw'] при авторизации в них записываются данные пользователя и при проверки входа с ними же идет сверка.

Как можно реализовать к проверку что бы нельзя было использовать один и тот же акаунт на 2х устройствах одновременно, либо к примеру при авторизации проверялось есть ли уже в сессиях совпадающие данные, либо что бы при авторизации разлогинило всех остальных пользователей с такими же данными в сессиях? что сделать лучше и по какому принципу?

Comment: Вот тут куча идей https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643591/php-session-login-one-per-user

Comment: Кроме того, хранить в сессии пароль - так себе идея. Зачем вам постоянная сверка пароля?

Comment: @ZhukovRoman да в чистом виде и даже зашифрованном в md5 да, не безопасно но в моем случае там несколько степеней шифрования с применением ключей, а сверка по 2м параметрам это как раз для большей надежности соответствия, ну в общем там свои нюансы есть)

Answer (score 0):

Есть очень простое решение.

1. При авторизации генерируйте некий хеш токен (только уникальный) и записывайте его в БД.
2. Дальше авторизируете пользователя по данному токену.

Таким образом, каждая новая авторизация будет генерировать новый токен, и авторизированным останется тот - кто авторизировался последним, а в предыдущих ссессия слетит, так как новый токен был сгенерирован.

Надеюсь понятно)

Comment: Интересная мысль, я думаю если ее развить и сохранять в базу данных seesion_id и id пользователя при авторизации и каждый раз при авторизации обновлять, а при действиях на сайте сравнивать и если не совпадают то разлогинивать пользователя